# Combining of esc_html command in PHP with HTML

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to combine specific commands from PHP with styles? I display data via following command:

```
echo esc_html( $text )
```

How is it possible to display the data like a headline `<h3>` tag?

I tried to simply add it, but that does not work:

```
'<h3>' . echo esc_html( $text ) . '</h3>';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $text ) . '</h3>';`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check [Escaping from HTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). In your case:

```
<h3><?php echo esc_html($text); ?></h3>
```

Alternatively, just feed [`echo`](https://www.php.net/echo) with as many arguments as needed:

```
<?php
echo '<h3>', esc_html($text), '</h3>';
```